# Auto-formatting input fields as user types

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile, jquery-plugins

I have a short piece of jQuery that will automatically insert a '/' character after the 2nd number entered into the date field.  This works as expected, but I cannot figure out how to allow the user to edit an incorrect entry by hitting the backspace because the code wants to keep entering the '/' after the second character has been entered, which keeps them from being able to start over.  I've tried to solve this on my own, but my skills just aren't up to par yet.  Below is my code; any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#cc-exp").keyup(function () {
        if ($(this).val().length == 2) {
            $(this).val($(this).val() + "/");
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

After continued research and experimentation, the solution ended up being to use .keypress instead of .keyup.  Below is the final code.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#cc-exp").keypress(function () {
        if ($(this).val().length == 2) {
            $(this).val($(this).val() + "/");
        }
    });
});
```